# Log exibition of TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit

Anyone know why do my TortoiseGIt is showing this way:
[image]

Instead this way:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are vertical sliders between the three elements with which you can adjust the sizes of the three.

Comment: I can not believe it was this...
Thank you very much ! it worked